# Exception while retrieving JSON data from URL in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

This is the `URL` i am calling --

```
private String url="http://mywebsite.com/requiredfolder/myfile.php";
```

This is the json output getting from the above URL --

```
{"wallpapers":[{"id":"9","video_url":"http://mywebsite.com/AndroidApp/VideoUploads/raman.das@gmail.com_X5x6MVgv_VID-20171202-WA0012.mp4","downloads":"0","fav":"0"},
{"id":"8","video_url":"http://mywebsite.com/AndroidApp/VideoUploads/raman.das@gmail.com_eFmWtS@I_Funny Kid playing.mp4","downloads":"0","fav":"0"},
{"id":"7","video_url":"http://mywebsite.com/AndroidApp/VideoUploads/raman.das@gmail.com_trE3U&%x_VID_20171019_163735.mp4","downloads":"0","fav":"0"},
{"id":"6","video_url":"http://mywebsite.com/AndroidApp/VideoUploads/raman.das@gmail.com_ROgIfyHG_Assamesefunny.mp4","downloads":"0","fav":"0"},
{"id":"3","video_url":"http://mywebsite.com/AndroidApp/VideoUploads/raman.das@gmail.com_C2z$XU6!_Bombay Ka Brahman.mp4","downloads":"0","fav":"0"}],"success":1,"count":"5"}
```

Now in my Java file when trying to read the same using the given code --

```
try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.d("Message : ","DefaultHttpClient done");
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            Log.d("Message : ","HttpGet done");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
            Log.d("Message : ","HttpResponse done");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            Log.d("Message : ","BufferedReader done");

            result = reader.readLine();
            //response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(url);
            //Log.d("Message : ","response done");
            //result = response.toString();
            Log.d("Message : ","result done");
            json = new JSONObject(result);
         }
          catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());
         }
```

In the above code, in line --

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
```

I am getting the runtime `execption`.

```
E/log_tag: Error in http connection!!android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Struggled a lot but not getting any idea, any lights on my code will be great.

Comment: `I am getting the runtime execption` share that exception with question

Comment: @Nilu........shared the runtime exception

Comment: you need to use **`AsyncTask`** to perform a networking operation

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException`

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
Try implementing your logic in a different background thread.

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html  NetworkOnMainThreadException read this